# weblogic 12c not loading application properties file

Tags: weblogic12c

We're moving from OC4J to WebLogic and have some properties files that reside outside of the EAR file. In OC4J we simply put them in the "applib" directory. Everything I've read so far about WebLogic says to put the file in the user_projects\domains\mydomain directory, but that's not working.

Is there another directory that I need to use or how do I force WebLogic to look in user_projects\domains\mydomain for the application properties files?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best solution, but at least a workaround. I edited `wls12130\oracle_common\common\bin\commEnv.cmd` and appended the domain home dir to this line:

```
set WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar;%PROFILE_CLASSPATH%;%ANT_CONTRIB%\lib\ant-contrib.jar;%CAM_NODEMANAGER_JAR_PATH%;%DOMAIN_HOME%
```